# B+ Trees Insertion Order

Tags: data-structures, tree, b-tree

How can the height of a B+ tree change in different insertion orders?

For example, given `n` values and 2 different insert orders. What is the maximum difference I can get between the heights of the 2 built trees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best-case height of a B+-tree (or any B-tree) is *log<sub>m</sub>n*. The worst-case height is *log<sub>m/2</sub>n*. (Per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#Best_case_and_worst_case_heights))

The maximum difference you can get is `worstCase - bestCase`, which is *log<sub>m/2</sub>n* - *log<sub>m</sub>n*, which reduces to

log<sub>m</sub>n ( 1 / (1 - log<sub>m</sub>2) - 1)

(*m* represents the maximum number of children any one tree node can have)